# Showing only the uptime from uptime [unix]

Tags: regex, sed, uptime

I'd like to trim the output from uptime

```
20:10  up 23 days,  3:28, 3 users, load averages: 3.84 1.06 0.64
```

so that it just shows:

```
23 days
```

I've tried using sed, but I'm not sure it's the right tool for the job, and don't have much experience using it.

How can I achieve the output I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider using `cut`.

```bash
uptime | tr "," " " | cut -f6-8 -d" "
```

seems to work on my MacBook. Here I've also used `tr` to kill an extraneous ",". There is a bit of an issue with different formats for short and long uptimes.

---

A possible sed solution:

```bash
uptime | sed 's/.*up \([^,]*\), .*/\1/'
```

which doesn't rely on the string "days" appearing in the output of `uptime`.

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted... both seem logical - maybe they were just in a bad mood!

Comment: Drive by downvotes happen. I just like to know if my solution is broken.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Arch Linux. Sorry I forgot to comment after down-voting.

Comment: @icco: With more info I might be able to fix it, but the gory details of the output from the "standard" utilities can vary from unix to unix, so this kinds of pipelines sometimes need tweaking...

Answer (score 5):

```bash
uptime | sed -E 's/^.+([0-9]+ days).+$/\1/'
```

Comment: \1 means the first captured group (which is in parentheses).

Comment: Note that when the substring `days` is not present (when a reboot has happened less than a day ago), this solution won't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use the shell without any external tools

```bash
$ var="20:10  up 23 days,  3:28, 3 users, load averages: 3.84 1.06 0.64"
$ var=${var/#*up}
$ echo ${var%%,*}
23 days
```

Comment: That's clever - didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Nice. I knew, in theory, but I never remember to use the bash extensions. (and it might be worth noting that this won't work with all shells...)

Comment: The original bourne shell, csh, don't know about ksh...all of unix doesn't run bash.

Answer (score 5):

The above solutions only display either the days or the hours. I realize that's what the OP was looking for but I was looking for including hours and minutes also. This displays both the days and hours/minutes when the system has been on for more than a day or just the hours when it's been less than one day:

```bash
uptime | sed 's/^.* up \+\(.\+\), \+[0-9] user.*$/\1/'
```

Props to black belt regex ninja Zach W for getting this working.

Comment: For a single user, the `uptime` output is "1 user", so it doesn't match "users" (plural) in the above. Change it to just "user" and it seems to work.

Comment: To match `user` or `users` you could alter the end of the regular expression to be `...users?.*$`. However, as `.*$` matches everything to the end of the line just omitting the `s`, as @PeterGibson suggests, to give `...user.*$` should work.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is simplest solution:

```bash
uptime | awk '{print $3}'
```

10

Answer (score 3):

```
uptime=$(</proc/uptime) ;  uptime=${uptime%%.*} ; days=$(( uptime/60/60/24 )); echo $days days
```

Comment: This is the only solution that uses /proc/uptime to get a consistens data format in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`uptime`'s output usually has "x days, y min" or "x days, y:z" - but sometimes if the uptime is *less* than a day, it has the hours/minutes as the first time-based output and doesn't bother with the number of days. The rest of the output is very consistent in terms of the number of columns. As a result of that, personally I've been using sed to just remove the last four columns:

```bash
$ uptime | sed -e 's/^ [^ ]* up \(.*\)\(,[^,]*\)\{4\}$/\1/'
31 days, 35 min
```

Alternatively, if you want just the most significant data, you can use a similar method others have mentioned where you just get the first bit of data. With less than a day, this would result in `<y> min` or `<y>:<z>`. With more than a day, it would result in `<x> days`.

```bash
$ uptime | sed -e 's/^ [^ ]* up \([^,]*\).*/\1/'
31 days
```

Lastly, if you want to reflect zero when it is less than 24 hours, you also have the option of using some math on `/proc/uptime` using `bc` or shell expressions:

```
$ uptime
 13:58:41 up 31 days, 55 min,  9 users,  load average: 0.80, 0.89, 0.81
$ echo $(( $(awk -F . '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 86400)) days
31 days

$ uptime
 13:59:01 up 21:18,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
$ echo $(( $(awk -F . '{print $1}' /proc/uptime) / 86400)) days
0 days
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```bash
$ uptime | grep -o "[0-9]* days"
70 days
```

Comment: this should be higher up

Answer (score 0):

```bash
uptime | cut -d',' -f 1 | cut -d 'p' -f 2-
```

If there are n days since the last reboot it will print n days. It will print a time in hh:mm should the uptime be less than a day.

```
$ uptime
12:20  up  1:36, 1 user, load averages: 2.75 2.63 2.26
$ uptime | cut -d',' -f 1 | cut -d 'p' -f 2-
  1:36
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct, but if any of you wanted to use awk then use:

```bash
uptime | awk '{ print $3,$4 }'
```

Result:

```
15 days,
```

Comment: If uptime is less than a day, this will output something like `5:04,  1` reflecting 5 hours, 4 minutes, and one user logged in.